# not able to connect to web server on AVD from linux

Tags: java, android, linux

I have the following configuration :

1) One AVD runing on port 5554 on Windows7 laptop having ip : 192.168.2.2.

2) One UDP server running on Linux (ubuntu) laptop; listening to port 9999. The ip of this is 192.168.2.4

3) One Wifi router through which all of these are connect. This acts as DHCP server & provides afore-stated ip to the laptops.

I have written an app in which I communicate with the UDP server on Linux which is working perfectly. This actually signifies there is no communication problem with my laptops (& program env). In the same app there is another thread which runs a WebServer listening on the TCP port 8888.

I try to connect to my webserver from AVD emulator it works perfectly & the page is displayed on the emulator. When I try to access the same from Windows / linux it doesn't work.
I read this page "http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html", particularly this section "Using Network Redirections", & redirected the following :

```
 redir add tcp:8888:8888
```

Now I try to access my web page from windows machine using google-chrome like this:

```
  "http://127.0.0.1:8888",
```

It works perfectly.

Problem :: The which I am facing is; When I try to access the same webpage from liunx machine in google-chrome by the following URL:

```
  http://192.168.2.2:8888 &
  http://10.0.2.15:8888
```

I am unable to reach my WebServer.

Kindly let me know what is that I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check that iptables on linux is not blocking your port for external connections.
AFAIK defaut iptables config is very restrictive.

Comment: my iptables &  firewall in linux are blank.Here is the o/p:Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
in fact I have switched off the firewall that is why my UDP connection works fine. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

check your router..route http://127.0.0.1:8888 has ot be allowed by router as its an internal IP not web IP

Comment: probably you need to access router admin at htp:/127.o.01:admin port and add the route

Comment: My router does not have any rules. I added the redirecting rule of port 8888 to my windows machine still it does not works. Kinldy help.